# Magento 2: Override ACL using custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, acl

I have updated the parent of a menu item which is coming from a third party extension. I have updated the menu item by my custom module's **menu.xml** file.

For instance, the menu was coming under **Marketing** >> **Promotions** >> **Gift Card History**. I have changed the menu position to **Reports** >> **Others** >> **Gift Card Accounting** by using the following code:

```
<update id="Magestore_Giftvoucher::gifthistory" title="Gift Cards Accounting" sortOrder="40" parent="Stream_ChangeCoreMenuPosition::others"/>
```

Since the parent of the menu item has been changed, now I need to modify the **ACL** of this item also.

For this, I don't want to make changes in the extension's **acl.xml** file. So I have created my own **acl.xml** in my custom module, but when I add the ACL entry for the modified menu position, I get the following error:

[image: ACL Error]

Please help me, how can I modify the ACL of the extension using my custom module (without modifying the extension's files).

Comment: Dont know why ... maybe add some code from your acl.xml? However .... +1

Comment: Can someone tell me who are the people who are downvoting on this question and why? Till now there are 8 downvotes without any reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to create a plugin to disable the existing ACL record first

In di.xml

```
<!-- remove existing record from ACL -->    
<type name="Magento\Integration\Helper\Data">
    <plugin name="my-acl-data" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Integration\Data" sortOrder="100" />
</type>
```

VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Integration\Data.php

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Integration;

class Data
{
    public function beforeMapResources(\Magento\Integration\Helper\Data $helper, array $resources)
    {
        $removed = $this->getIdsToRemove();
        foreach ($resources as $key => $resource) {
            if (in_array($resource['id'], $removed)) {
                unset($resources[$key]);
            }
        }
        return [$resources];
    }
    private function getIdsToRemove()
    {
        return [
            'Magestore_Giftvoucher::gifthistory',
        ];
    }
}
```

This will remove Magestore_Giftvoucher::gifthistory

Then add your own records in acl.xml : VendorName_ModuleName::yourRecord

Comment: Okay, thanks @melaxon. I will check and will get back to you soon.

Comment: Great @melaxon, it worked for me. But for that, I had to add the menu item instead of updating the existing one. Also, need to override/pluginize the controller also.

Comment: e.g. im menu.xml 
    
    `<add id="NewVendor_NewModule::some_id" title="My new item" translate="title" module="NewVendor_NewModule" sortOrder="1" parent="Another_Module::another_item" action="some_action/blah_blah" resource="NewVendor_NewModule::something_manage"/>`
    
    The best way imho is to search through existing Magento modules for some examples that look like yours and can inspire your

Comment: how would you override existing third party plugin(LandofCoder) having acl.xml and menu.xml in order to give permission to access that module to other user roles?. Admin is able to access that module but I also want that module to be accessible by other userroles. i have put up my work over here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326318/magento-2-how-to-override-role-resourcesacl-xml-and-menu-xml. this concept is really interesting it would be great if someone can guide me through this.